Reorder pinned extensions in Firefox
Because I develop websites and clearing the cache for a specific website is still not an accessible feature that browsers offer by default, I installed an add-on to do it.
I got into the habit of clicking the last pinned Add-on in the toolbar several dozen times a day when I develop, which looks like a "⌫", but recently needed to add another Addon that appeared to its right and looks like a ️:

Now I have the habit of clicking the very last icon and I often click on the wrong one.
On macOS, rearranging items in the menu bar or on the Dock is extremely simple and intuitive, you press an action key (CMD) and drag around the icons in the menu bar or simply drag around the icons of the Dock.
However the Firefox documentation makes it confusing to rearrange what happens in the top extensions bar.
This page mentions moving extensions "Up" or "Down", but that applies to when they are accessed through the puzzle piece icon .
This made me think that I had to unpin the Extension before being able to access it in the jigsaw puzzle piece and then access the "Move up or down" feature and then repin it.
Obviously this was way too complicated to be true.
How can I change the order of pinned extensions in Firefox on macOS?
Firefox 130.0 (64-bit) and MacBook Pro running Sonoma



Right-click the Toolbar.
Select Customize Toolbar....
Move the cursor over an icon. It should change to an image of a hand.
Grab the icon and move it.
Click Done to save changes.


Thank you! Right-clicking the toolbar itself instead of the icons is one of the countless possible things I hadn't tried.

In a limited test (four extensions), I was able to set the order I wanted based on the order I pinned the extension.
I was also able to move an extension from the middle to the end by unpinning and re-pinning it.
So, in your case, unpin "⌫", then re-pin it and it should be last on the tool bar.

Far easier to just drag to the correct location.

@DrMoishePippik I agree. It was the first thing I tried - But they wouldn't move. If it can be done, please explain how
